# How can I remove the gaps and make it a single stack while visualizing in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I am visualizing some data and I need to remove the gaps between the cells (It can be seen clearly in the picture). 
 The white gaps between red and blue cells/elements. 
[image]

The red represents 'no', while the blue, 'yes'. The code snippet is:

```
fig = px.bar(
        data, 
        x = policy_type,
        y = 'State', 
        color = policy_type,
        title = title
)
```

Comment: what is policy_type here?

Comment: The policy_type is a string. I am working on visualizing some data related to the States and their various policies.

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in the plotly [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#aggregating-into-single-colored-bars). You can use `histogram` to avoid the striped look. It has a similar call signature to `bar`:

```
fig = px.histogram(
        data, 
        x = policy_type,
        y = 'State', 
        color = policy_type,
        barmode = 'group',
        title = title
)
```

Comment: Great! You could mark this as the accepted answer to let others know it works as well.